# Is it OK to call a programming language a software?

Tags: terminology

Can I call Java or 'C' a software?  For example, is the following statement correct: 'Python is a software'.

Comment: Why would you think this is correct? It's not.

Comment: A programming language is a *specification* - grammar and rules of how such should be interpreted and/or compiled and/or executed. *Specifications are not 'software'*. However, *implementation* of such languages like gcc, clang, perl/ruby/python (the programs which implement said languages!), javac (and the jvm) etc. *are* software.

Comment: @user2864740 Please turn this into an answer, because it is better than mine ;-)

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, you made it clear. So, compilers like clang and gcc which compile the programs are softwares , not the language itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that what translates what you wrote in a certain programming language into binary code is a software. So your Java or C compiler is a software, the languages Java or C are just "words" and syntax.